# call constructor in a generic way

Tags: typescript, generics, nestjs

I have a simple controller, which I want to write in a generic way:

```
@Controller('users')
export class UserController extends BaseController<User, UserEntity> {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {
    super(userService);
  }

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return new UserEntity(await this.userService.createEntity(createUserDto));
  }
}
```

The `BaseController` class looks like this:

```
@Controller()
export abstract class BaseController<T, T2> {
  constructor(private readonly service: BaseService<T>) {}

  @Post()
  async create(@Body() createDto: DeepPartial<T>): Promise<T2> {
    return new UserEntity(await this.service.createEntity(createDto));
  }
}
```

As you see, I replaced every concrete tpye with generics: `T` is of type `User` (in this question not relevant), `T2` is of type `UserEntity`.

`UserEntity` is a class and has it's own constructor. As you see, I call this constructor in the `create` method. The question is, how can I call this constructor in a generic way?

In the future, there will be other entities with other classes, but the constructor will be always the same (just with a different type), f. e. in the `UserEntity` class:

```
constructor(partial: Partial<UserEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
```

Is this even possible? I can use DI, if necessary.

Comment: Maybe try adding a generic UserEntity as a parameter to BaseController constructor? You can use ClassConstructor from class-transformer package to narrow the type